# Why i'm i not able start noir server in intelli idea ID..?

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea, leiningen

I'm totally new to clojure... here is what I do

```
 (use 'Yuhuru.server) // works fine, i mean gives nil

(def mysrv (noir.server/start 8080)) //now it gives
```

> failed Server@9bfee2: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows
>   Sockets error: 10106: create java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized
>   Windows Sockets error: 10106: create (NO_SOURCE_FILE:2)

but using commandline i'm able start server.. is there any setting i'm missing in ID.. Please throw some light..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds something like this: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9457989

Go here: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=4050 ; scroll down to the comments at 2010-06-08 20:39:35, it sounds like an issue with LaClojure (I'm assuming that you're using that...)

Answer (score 3):

Problems with IntelliJ REPL not being able to create sockets under Windows used to come from the system environment variables not being propagated to the child JVM REPL process. Without these Windows won't be able to create a socket.

To test if your IntelliJ suffers from this problem, do a `(System/getenv)` from the REPL in IntelliJ and you'll see you get an empty map, instead of a map filled with your system variables like you get with a REPL from the commandline.

This is a recurring issue in various versions of IntelliJ/LaClojure. It was fixed in an earlier IntelliJ 10 / LaClojure version (0.3.92), but the last LaClojure update for IntelliJ 10 (0.3.102) [broke it](https://github.com/JetBrains/la-clojure/issues/8) again.

I verified it should be fixed in the current IntelliJ idea 11.0.2 #IC-111.277 with LaClojure 0.4.30 combination. Downgrading LaClojure  to [0.3.92](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?action=download&id=9977) should work as well if you have to keep IntelliJ 10.